# Execute a function as the very final thing of an asynchronous Node.js script

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Let's say you have a Node.js script that runs a lot of async functions that request data from several servers. You never know the time when you get the answers and the callbacks are executed.

What is an easy method to execute a function of that script as the last thing to do, when all the asynchronous stuff in the query is done?

Comment: First, you gotta fix this problem: *"You never know the time when you get the answers and the callbacks are executed"* otherwise, what you're asking for isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so often, this depends on how your asynchronous code works, i.e. if you are using callbacks or promises.

#### Using callbacks

You might use a library such as [async](http://caolan.github.io/async/) for this. It allows you to run several asynchronous tasks sequentially or in parallel or in whatever other style you want to, but all of those options have thing in common: Once all tasks have been completed, async runs a final callback.

If you put your code into that callback, you get exactly what you asked for.

To give an example of the syntax (by running all tasks in parallel):

```
async.parallel([
  done => {
    // This is the first task.
  },
  done => {
    // This is the second task.
  },
  done => {
    // This is the third task.
  }
], err => {
  // This is the final callback.
});
```

Of course, it does not matter how many tasks you have, and if you don't want to run them in parallel, use one of the other functions of async instead, e.g. `series` if you want to run one after the other.

#### Using promises

If you have a bunch of promises, things even become easier as you may use the `Promise.all` function to wait until all the promises have been resolved. Then you can have one final handler to do your final stuff.

Again, to give an example, lets suppose that `p1`, `p2` and `p3` are promises, then you can do this:

```
Promise.all([ p1, p2, p3 ]).then(results => {
  // ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If using promises, put them all in a `Promise.all` call, and then chain a `then` onto that call. It will get called when all the promises inside the `.all` call resolve.

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
  .then(allPromiseData => console.log('all the async promises are done');
```